# HelloService and TodoService

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack self host windows service question, at the [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/v3/src/StarterTemplates/StarterTemplates.Common) there are two Services: `TodoService.cs` and `HelloService.cs`.

I am a little confused, are they different examples or related each other?

```
//Register REST Paths
[Route("/todos")]
[Route("/todos/{Id}")]
public class Todo //REST Resource DTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}

//Todo REST Service implementation
public class TodoService : RestServiceBase<Todo>
{
    public TodoRepository Repository { get; set; }  //Injected by IOC

    public override object OnGet(Todo request)
    {
        if (request.Id == default(long))
            return Repository.GetAll();

        return Repository.GetById(request.Id);
    }

    //Called for new and update
    public override object OnPost(Todo todo)
    {
        return Repository.Store(todo);
    }

    public override object OnDelete(Todo request)
    {
        Repository.DeleteById(request.Id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And

```
 /// <summary>
/// Define your ServiceStack web service request (i.e. the Request DTO).
/// </summary>  
[Description("ServiceStack's Hello World web service.")]
[Route("/hello")]
[Route("/hello/{Name*}")]
public class Hello
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Define your ServiceStack web service response (i.e. Response DTO).
/// </summary>
public class HelloResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{       
    public string Result { get; set; }      
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Create your ServiceStack web service implementation.
/// </summary>
public class HelloService : ServiceBase<Hello>
{
    protected override object Run(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are separate examples of different services you can build with ServiceStack. The ServiceStack examples are made available in a single solution called `ServiceStack.Examples`, but it contains separate projects.

You are looking in a directory called `StarterTemplates.Common`, this is simply shared by several of the examples for code reusability. The folder structure does not indicate that `TodoService.cs` and `HelloService.cs` are directly related.

---

The individual projects of the ServiceStack Examples, [can be seen here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/v3).

> #### [Backbone.js TODO app with REST and Redis backend](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3)
>
> [image: Backbone REST and Redis TODOs]
>
> #### [Creating a Hello World Web service from scratch](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3)
>
> [image: ServiceStacks Hello, World!]